# rosinstall stuck on perception_pcl

Tags: ros, rosinstall, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and using these instructions  http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup/Source

During the "rosinstall ~/ros turtlebot.rosinstall" part the installation got stuck on

[perception_pcl] Installing https://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl-1.0.2 (None) to /home/owner/ros/perception_pcl

I lefted it on all night and there was still no progress, i checked for other installation methods also, but i wasn't sure what's the same package was called in synaptic  package manager

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39655/rosinstall-stuck-on-perception_pcl/) by [req09](https://answers.ros.org/users/2908/req09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh i think its what joq said, i'm on 12.04 precise, the packages for this doesn't have turtlebot desktop, i see clear path, not sure if that is the correct package, it's description said it provide a central repository of software and launch files intended for deployment on the turtlebot

---

Originally posted by [req09](https://answers.ros.org/users/2908/req09/) with karma: 16 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0